# Page redirects when clicked anywhere in a <div>

Tags: php, html

I am designing a website, and i encountered a problem.
In the following page "samgatha.org/register.php", wherever i click inside the form-box, it redirects to "samgatha.org/register.php". I am not able to find the problem.
Below i am posting the main code for the registeration form, i am not including the template code.

```
<div id="register-box">
<?php
  require 'connection.php';
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
    if((isset($_POST['enthu_name']))&&(isset($_POST['enthu_email']))&&(isset($_POST['enthu_contact']))&&(isset($_POST['college_name']))&&(isset($_POST['branch']))&&(isset($_POST['pass']))) {

        $var_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['enthu_name']);
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$var_name)) {
            die('Only letters and white spaces allowed in Name<br>');
        }
        $var_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['enthu_email']);
        if(!filter_var($var_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            die("Invalid email format<br>");
        }
        $var_contact = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['enthu_contact']);
        $var_college = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['college_name']);
        $var_branch = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['branch']);

        $passwd = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['pass']));

        $v1 = rand(0,getrandmax());
        $v2 = rand(0,getrandmax());
        $ac_conf = $v1.$v2;
        $ac_conf_hash = md5($v1.$v2);
        $v1 = rand(0,getrandmax());
        $v2 = rand(0,getrandmax());
        $fo_pass = $v1.$v2;

        $query = "insert into student_detail (name,email,phno,college,branch,password,acc_confirm_code,forgot_pass_code)".
                "values".
                "('$var_name','$var_email','$var_contact','$var_college','$var_branch','$passwd','$ac_conf','$fo_pass')";

        $retval = mysql_query($query);
        if(!$retval) {
          die('Could not register'.mysql_error());
        }
        $reg_conf_code = "http://samgatha.org/reg_conf.php?acconf=".$ac_conf_hash."&suse=".$var_email;
        $reg_conf = "Please click on the link to activate<br>".$reg_conf_code;

        mail($_POST['enthu_email'],"Samgatha Account Confirmation (no reply) link",$reg_conf);

        header('Location: http://samgatha.org/login.php');
      }
      else {
      echo "Please enter details to continue <br>";
    }
  }
 ?>

Welcome to samgatha registrations. <br>
Please fill out the following form to participate in samgatha.
<form id="sam_register" action="register.php" method="post">

  <div class="reg-box-in">
  <label class="i2" id="ii1" for="enthu_name">Name : </label>
  <input class="i1" type="text" name="enthu_name" id="enthu_name"> <br>
  </div>

  <div class="reg-box-in">
  <label class="i2" id="ii2" for="enthu_email">E-mail Address : </label>
  <input class="i1" type="text" name="enthu_email" id="enthu_email"> <br>
  </div>

  <div class="reg-box-in">
  <label class="i2" id="ii3" for="enthu_contact">Phone No : +91</label>
  <input class="i1" type="text" name="enthu_contact" id="enthu_contact"> <br>
  </div>

  <div class="reg-box-in">
  <label class="i2" id="ii4" for="college_name">Institute : </label>
  <input class="i1" type="text" name="college_name" id="college_name"> <br>
  </div>

  <div class="reg-box-in">
  <label class="i2" id="ii5" for="branch">Discipline : </label>
  <input class="i1" type="text" name="branch" id="branch"> <br>
  </div>

  <div class="reg-box-in">
  <label class="i2" id="ii6" for="password">Password : </label>
  <input class="i1" type="text" name="pass" id="pass" maxlength="30"> <br>
  </div>

  <div class="reg-box-in">
  <button type="submit" name="register">Register</button> <br>
  </div>
</form>     


</div>
```

And this is not the problem only with the register page.
You can check the website samgatha.org.

Comment: Do you have any javascript in the page for form validation or other that could be causing it?

Comment: No, i dont have any javascript.

Comment: Hey you have two closing `div`. This might leads to invalid HTML.

Comment: the first closing <div> was that of submit button, i fixed it.. still problem isnt solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various html issues

Unclosed link

```
<a href="login.php"><div id="register" class="lay2"><div id="registert">Sign In/Up</div></div>
```

Comment: fixed it. still problem exists (thanks to point it out though)

Comment: @klbm9999 Still not fixed when I reload page

Comment: i just put the </a> tag. the problem is not solved by that

Comment: @klbm9999 I'm still not seeing a closing </a> tag and that is your problem

Comment: @klbm9999 I would try sending your page through http://validator.w3.org/ as it could help trouble shoot html formatting issues

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="register-box">
<?php
  require 'connection.php';
  if (!empty($_POST)) {

        $var_name = mysql_real_escape_string(<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]); ?>);
        //-- same used for post ------------
        header('Location: http://samgatha.org/login.php');
      }
      else {
      echo "Please enter details to continue <br>";
    }
  }
 ?>

Welcome to samgatha registrations. <br>
Please fill out the following form to participate in samgatha.
 <form action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?> method="post">

  <div class="reg-box-in">
  <label class="i2" id="ii1" for="enthu_name">Name : </label>
  <input class="i1" type="text" name="enthu_name" id="enthu_name"> <br>
  </div>

  <div class="reg-box-in">
  <label class="i2" id="ii2" for="enthu_email">E-mail Address : </label>
  <input class="i1" type="text" name="enthu_email" id="enthu_email"> <br>
  </div>

  <div class="reg-box-in">
  <label class="i2" id="ii3" for="enthu_contact">Phone No : +91</label>
  <input class="i1" type="text" name="enthu_contact" id="enthu_contact"> <br>
  </div>

  <div class="reg-box-in">
  <label class="i2" id="ii4" for="college_name">Institute : </label>
  <input class="i1" type="text" name="college_name" id="college_name"> <br>
  </div>

  <div class="reg-box-in">
  <label class="i2" id="ii5" for="branch">Discipline : </label>
  <input class="i1" type="text" name="branch" id="branch"> <br>
  </div>

  <div class="reg-box-in">
  <label class="i2" id="ii6" for="password">Password : </label>
  <input class="i1" type="text" name="pass" id="pass" maxlength="30"> <br>
  </div>

  <div class="reg-box-in">
  <button type="submit" name="register">Register</button> <br>

</form>     
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: i didnt understand what you did, could you tell me?

Answer (score -1):

There is `<a>` tag on `register-box` which redirects to `login.php`. Please check your code it puts `<a>` tag.